# Create new table or insert data into a existing table?

Tags: database-design

I am new in DB and I have a problem here.
I need to store a expression into a table using tree structure. like this:
[image: For example, this is the expression]

The unique ID of this expression is:1

I first transform it into a tree structure,like:

[image]

Then, I try to save the tree into a table called "Node". like this:
[image]

And my problem is: for each expression, should I save the tree structure into the existing 'Node' table(using ExpressionID to distinguish expressions)? Or should I create a new table for each expression (of course, using the Expression name as the table name)?

Maybe it's not efficient to create a lot of tables?

Thanks!
If it's necessary, I can also post other related tables here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a new table. That would result in as many tables as you have expressions, making the whole system much harder to maintain.

Also when the DBMS has to find the right table among many (for the given table name), this also costs some performance, potentially more so than finding a bunch of rows in a well-indexed single table. And icing on the cake is that you are probably wasting a lot of space - a table grows in pages and if your expressions are much smaller then a page (typically 4-8KB, depending on a database), you'll end-up with many pages that are almost completely empty.

As a sidenote, do you even need to store individual expression nodes as separate rows in the database? This makes sense if you want to somehow search or analyze individual nodes, but if all you need is to read and execute the expression *as a whole*, then just storing the whole expression (in its string format or encoded as XML or whatever) in a CLOB/BLOB makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't create a new table for each expression, store them in a single table. It's the regular DB way. A table is not an object.